# how to get value from edit box on installshield dialog

Tags: dialog, installshield

i have a VB6 project and want to make own dialog window to get user input value and save it to text file.
Please explain how this is done?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a home work site. Do some research, show some progress and the SO community will help you when you feel stuck. No one will do the complete work and explain the code line by line,

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. i search a lot of different sites, but did not find any practical idea.

Answer (score 0):

**How to get user input value?**

Please use `CtrlGetText`:

[image]

- ControlID can only be found in project type: 
  `InstallScript, InstallScript MSI, InstallScript Object`:

[image]